# Can anyone explain to me why my variable "sum" is not calculating the sum of array "arrPrice"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to see the sum of values that are in the array `arrPrice` at the last cell of the table. But the `sum` variable is just keeping the last value I inserted into the table. Can someone explain to me why something like that is happening? Is my style of creating the table rows faulty?

```js
function insert() {
  var i = 0;
  var t = 0;
  var c = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var arrName = [];
  var arrPrice = [];
  
  arrName[i] = document.getElementById("name").value;
  arrPrice[i] = document.getElementById("price").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("tabl3");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = arrName[i];
  cell2.innerHTML = arrPrice[i];
  i++;

  while (t < arrPrice.length) {
    arrPrice[t] = arrPrice[t] * 1;
    sum = sum + arrPrice[t];
    t++;
  }

  document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br> Price: <input type="number" id="price"><br>
<button id="ins" onclick="insert()">Insert</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table id="tabl3">
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td id="totalprice"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you think `arrPrice.length` is? `while(t<arrPrice.length)`. < looping over an array of 1....  Why are you also using `i` and `t`? Every time you call your insert code you reset all the variables.

Comment: arrPrice[i] = document.getElementById("price").value; why you use i here?

Comment: You should keep variables that need to persist between `insert` calls outside that function. otherwise, you start with an empty array of prices every time and just add the one price.

Comment: Yes. I just realized that I have declared my variables inside the function, which is stupid. Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting `arrPrice` every run, which sets it to the most recent element. One solution is to make the array global and append to it in the function call:

```
var arrPrice = [];
function insert() {
  var i = 0;
  var t = 0;
  var c = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var arrName = [];
  
  arrName[i] = document.getElementById("name").value;
  arrPrice.push(document.getElementById("price").value);

  var table = document.getElementById("tabl3");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = arrName[i];
  cell2.innerHTML = arrPrice[i];
  i++;

  while (t < arrPrice.length) {
    arrPrice[t] = arrPrice[t] * 1;
    sum = sum + arrPrice[t];
    t++;
  }

  document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

EDIT: I'm seeing a lot of people commenting that you're setting `sum` each time. While changing this will make your code work, the logic is broken. Your method is to create an array and sum it up every time you call `insert`, not to add to a running sum. I assume the other answers were looking for a quick fix and didn't mind breaking the logic of your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function you do `sum = 0`. So every time when you call your function your sum become 0. To solve it just make your `sum` global. Just put it outside of your function.

Comment: Please don't use global variables!

Comment: and this is not a solution at all

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting `sum` each time you insert a new value. Try recalculating it each time. No looping required

```js
function insert() {
 
  let insertedName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let insertedPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);

  var table = document.getElementById("tabl3");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = insertedName;
  cell2.innerHTML = insertedPrice;
  
  const totalPrice = document.getElementById('totalprice');
  totalPrice.innerText = parseFloat(totalPrice.innerText || "0") + insertedPrice;
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 150px
}
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br> Price: <input type="number" id="price"><br>
<button id="ins" onclick="insert()">Insert</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table id="tabl3">
  <tr>
    <td>Item</td>
    <td>Price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td id="totalprice"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```